# google docs uploaded file timestamp

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I use google docs api (Python) and use metadata description field to keep original file date and time. I tried Google drive client app and see that it keeps uploaded file original timestamp and then google docs api allows to see it.
Is it possible now to set file date and time using google docs API?
Thank you

Comment: Which timestamp are you referring to in the Documents List Entry?

Answer (score 0):

When uploading or modifying a file using the Google Document List API the `updated` and `published` attributes of the file entry should be automatically filled. All you should need is to read these values.